# Data repeat in UITableView when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I use bellow codes to show data on TableView but when scrolling, data repeat and other data lost.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [FileCompletedArray count];

}
```

cellForRowatindexpath ():

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *FileNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
        FileNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        FileNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        NSLog(@"Reseversed TEMP array %@",FileCompletedArray);
        FileNameLabel.text =[FileCompletedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: FileNameLabel];
        [FileNameLabel release];



    }
        return cell;
}
```

Do you have any solutions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use cell Identifier different

For example like bellow...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        /// write your code here..
    }
}
```

**OR** set `nil` like bellow..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";    

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
        /// write your code here..
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is one of the solutions, I think `cell` won't be reused by this code. Every time it creates a new `cell`.

Comment: This code will not reuse the cell, rather create new cell each time. This will have performance issues in case the data source is large. Also it is not a good coding practice to **not reuse** the cell.

Comment: no this not problem here when you have a lot of data then you can use reusebility of custome cell.. :)

Comment: this code is making cell reuse impossible. that's wrong with this. nobody is jealous…

Comment: @vikingosegundo no mate not only for this answer but from some time when i give answer after that some one downvote me without any reason.. also here you are right that for many record this method not good but for that i use one of my custom method which is overcome this problem.. i will post that if problem occured Mate.. :)

Comment: This is a problem, as soon not all rows fit on the screen at once. and looking at your profile I dont think that u receive a extraordinary amount of down votes.

Comment: The solution given above is so so wrong because it is basically killing the key feature of view re-usability. When we keep same view and just change content, that way we increase the speed and decreases the memory consumption but above solution is doing both things in a vice-versa way.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is generated because Your `UITableView` Reuse Cell instant of create new one.
I give you some suggestion that may be helpful for you.

1)   add `Controller` in between

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        /// Your code of initialization of controller;
    }

    /// set property of controllers such like (Text UILabel, image of UIImageView...etc) .
 return cell;

}
```

1) Add Your `Controller` to `cell.contentView.`

**EDITED:**

Before You follow my Edited Answer i want to tell you that following code is bad for memory management because it will create new cell for each rows of `UITableView`, so be careful for it.

But it is better for if `UITableView` Have Limited row about (50-100 may be ) os use following code if is it suitable for you.

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
          /// Your whole code of controllers;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the text of the label only when creating a new cell. However, during cell reuse, new cell is not created. Hence your code for setting/changing text is not working. You can use this modified code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *FileNameLabel=nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        FileNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
        FileNameLabel.tag = 1001;
        FileNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        FileNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: FileNameLabel];
        [FileNameLabel release];
    }
    if(!FileNameLabel)
        FileNameLabel = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
    FileNameLabel.text =[FileCompletedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Alternatively you can use the default [`textLabel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of creating and adding new label

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *FileNameLabel=nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text =[FileCompletedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same problem, the problem occurs when we reuse the cells. At the time of reusing the data is already present in it and we write some more data also, to sort out this, i did a minor change to my table view delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath. Here the code which i use always using table view.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

return cell;
```

}

**The for loop gets executed when we are reusing some cell and what it does is removing all the previous data present in UITableViewCell**

Hope this will help someone.