# DataArray changed but on UITableView not show new data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I debug `DataArray` changed but on `UITableView` still not show new data get from `DataArray`.
 This is my codes:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *FileNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
        FileNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        FileNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
         NSLog(@"File Temp 4 array: %@", temp);
        FileNameLabel.text =[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: FileNameLabel];
        [FileNameLabel release];

    }
        return cell;
}
```

And function `update()` in `ViewWillAppear`

```
-(void) update
{
      if([FileCompletedArray count] != [temp count])
      {
            temp = [FileCompletedArray mutableCopy];
            NSLog(@"File Temp 1 array: %@", temp);
            [_tableView reloadData];
            NSLog(@"File Temp 2 array: %@", temp);
       }
}
```

Do you have solution?

Comment: It's very hard to read code where naming conventions are broken several times in each line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data repeat in UITableView when scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467580/data-repeat-in-uitableview-when-scrolling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call reloadData, the cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called again, but since the cells are already created, the tableview will reuse the cell, so the proper method here is to get the label inside the cell and update its text outside the `if(cell == nil)` block. I have modified your code and updated one is given below.

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    UILabel *FileNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
    FileNameLabel.tag = 1000;
    FileNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
    FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    FileNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     NSLog(@"File Temp 4 array: %@", temp);
    [cell.contentView addSubview: FileNameLabel];
    [FileNameLabel release];

}


UILabel *fileNameLbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
fileNameLbl.text =[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Please check whether this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a cell reuse issue, because you're code to set the cell text (`FileNameLabel.text =[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`) is only run when you're creating a new cell instance.

You need to differentiate between what settings are required when you create a new cell and what settings are required when you reuse / prepare to show a cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different section then assign value with bellow code to `FileNameLabel`

```
FileNameLabel.text =[[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```